# Addition of velocities

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, inertial-frames, relative-motion

Let's say a car ,in straight line motion ,has a speed of V m/s  (in the absence of wind) and let the speed of wind be W m/s the in the same direction . What is the speed of the car in the presence of the wind ?
It is intuitively clear that it is V + W  m/s . But how to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is intuitively clear that it is V + W m/s .

It's not.

This may roughly be correct for an airplane and all velocities referenced to the ground, but it's not true for a car.

The car moves by applying torque to the wheels. The resulting velocity is a the result of the equilibrium between the power put out by the engine and all loss mechanisms: drive train, roll resistance, tire loss, wind resistance etc. Wind in the drive direction will reduce the loss through wind resistance somewhat since the relative speed between car and air molecules goes down, but the overall effect on the car's velocity is much less than the wind speed.